# CSS, стоит ли писать свойства в 2 столбца?

Tags: css

Например:

```css
div{
  height: 50px; width: 100px;
}
```

Хочется уменьшить кол-во строк, ибо код получается как макаронина.
Конечно, не все свойства, а те что поменьше размерами и схожие по смыслу(height – width, align-items – justify-content)

Comment: Я Вам больше скажу: Вы можете вообще все стили писать в одну строку (с соблюдением, конечно, синтаксиса). Откройте и посмотрите любой пожатый css-файл (bootstrap.min.css, например) - там даже пробелов нету.

Comment: Читал один подобный код, пожалуй не надо. Глаза режет

Comment: Причём здесь "читал"? Код ужимают не для того, чтобы Вы его потом мучительно читали, а для повышения производительности при отправке в продакшн.

Comment: Ради интереса решил посмотреть, а там было это. Учту)

Comment: делают же минифицированные файлы ..и  css тоже

Comment: Пишите код в том виде, в котором будет удобно его читать, а при публикации минимизируйте его, для этого существует много инструментов. Также в devtools можно переводить минимизированный код в человекочитаемый вид.